A website can make requests, but I get CORS error, how is this possible?
When I open www.example.com in the browser and look at the trace of requests in the devtools I see that this website made a request to ux.example.com, but the original website domain is www.example.com.
So I copied this request as fetch from the networks tab and pasted it in the console. It gave me the CORS error

Access to fetch at
'https://ux.example.com/'
from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS
policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I really don't understand how it's possible, could you please explain it?

I can only guess at what you really observed. However, the same-origin policy applies to fetch requests, but not to stylesheet loading requests, for example.

To complement @HeikoTheißen's comment, I would direct you to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_network_access

@HeikoTheißen it wasn't stylesheet or a script, it was a fetch for json data

@MikhailBeloborodov In that case, please share more details. Otherwise, I'm afraid this question is likely to be closed as "not reproducible".

So I've figured out what was happening. Basically this website has an iframe to the other site and so this request was made by the iframe and I could not replicate it.

This afternoon I have the same problem, try adding an "s" after http.
I mean "httpS" XDXD
"https://example.com
I hope this can help you

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
